# threading.Condition notification getting missed

Tags: python

I create sample program for understanding `threading.Condition` in python. In which producer class will generate some numbers and send to the consumer class. The consumer class will simply take the square of the  number received.

Code:

```
class ConditionProducer(threading.Thread):
    """ Create numbers till limt """

    def __init__(self, condition, limit, buf):
        super(ConditionProducer, self).__init__()
        self.limit = limit
        self.condition = condition

    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.limit):
            with self.condition:
                print "Creating Number %d" % i
                buf[0] = i
                self.condition.notify()
                time.sleep(.5)

class ConditionConsumer(threading.Thread):
    """ Create Square of number generated by producer """

    def __init__(self, condition, buf):
        super(ConditionConsumer, self).__init__()
        self.condition = condition

    def run(self):
        with self.condition:            
            while True:
                sqr = buf[0] * buf[0]
                print "The Square of number is %d" % sqr
                self.condition.wait()
                time.sleep(.1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    buf = [-1]
    condition = threading.Condition()
    t1 = ConditionProducer(condition, 10, buf)
    t2 = ConditionConsumer(condition, buf)
    t2.start()
    t1.start()
```

I got following output:

```
ubuntu:~$ python thread.py 
The Square of number is 1

Creating Number 0
The Square of number is 0
Creating Number 1
The Square of number is 1
Creating Number 2
Creating Number 3
Creating Number 4
Creating Number 5
Creating Number 6
Creating Number 7
Creating Number 8
Creating Number 9
The Square of number is 81
```

In the above code consumer sleep less than producer sleep time. So there is no chance that consumer will miss the producer's notification. So, why square of some numbers are missing in the output?

Answer (score 0):

i cannot pin point the portion where the problem is but could you use `lock` when ever you are changing the common list which is shared by the producer and consumer.
This problem is due to the race condition mostly.